# Animated movie where boy get transported to another world and is helped by shape-shifters.

Tags: story-identification

In this movie he flies around on a bed and the shape shifters are on a secondary quest to find one of their kind, which they eventually do and fly their way to safety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Little Nemo: Adventures in Slumberland](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104740/) from 1989.

> A young boy whose dreams transcend reality is sucked into his own fantasy, which is everything he has dreamed of until he unleashes a century old secret that may not only destroy this perfect dream world but reality itself.

**Trailer**